# Pass msg_id with jQuery into Twitter Bootstrap modal

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an jquery modal. So now I want to pass value of msg_id to modal.

HTML code:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#com" id="<?php echo $msg_id; ?>">Comment</a>
```

--

```
<div id="com" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none; ">
<div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
        <h3><?php echo $msg_id; ?></h3>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
    <h4>Text in a modal</h4>
    <p>You can add some text here.</p>              
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Call to action</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
</div>
```

This is the screenshoot.
If I click comment in table 1, it show and I can see the pass value.
But if I click comment in table 2, it show same with the table 1. Should be different because each have an different msg_id.

[image]

So how can I pass the msg_id value into modal with the case of my code ?
Appreciate with your helps.
Thanks

Comment: What's the JavaScript code you're using to launch the modal dialog?

Comment: Hi, you can check the demo here : http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/modal-example.html

Answer (score 1):

You must add some class attribute to your a tag, for example "modal-toggler"

```
<a  class="modal-toggler" data-toggle="modal" href="#com" 
    id="<?php echo $msg_id; ?>">
    Comment
</a>
```

And call some jQuery script like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".modal-toggler").click(function(){
    var _id = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#com h3").text(_id);
    $("#com").show();
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: I've tried the code, it just show 1 msg_id although there are a some message.

Comment: So, what do you want to see? This code apply anchor id to your modal or not?

Comment: Hi, I give you the screen shoot of my case. See that in top